# Button tap callback

Tags: nativescript

I've got something like this in my xml file

`<Button id="info-button" text="Test" tap="{{ onInfoTap }}" />`

On tapping I want to call a method in my context object.

I'm getting a compile time warning of:

JS: Binding: Property: 'onInfoTap' is invalid or does not exist. SourceProperty: 'onInfoTap'

It's just a 1-way callback - not a property. If i remove the double curly braces then I don't get the callback into my context object.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using MVVM structure? If so, you can define a tap listener for button on Model page that calls the function in ViewModel:

In XML:

```
<Button tap="onInfoTap" />
```

In `.js` file:

```
export function onInfoTap(args) {
    // Just for example, pageViewModel is the page binding context object
    pageViewModel.yourFunction();
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
class PageViewModel extends Observable {
    public yourFunction() {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

This is what I'm used to do. If you don't want to remove the curly braces, I suggest this:

```
class PageViewModel extends Observable {
    public yourFunction() {
        // Code here
    }
    this.set("onInfoTap", yourFunction);
}
```

If these things don't help you, could you please post some more your code so that I can understand it clearer.

Comment: Thanks - I did the first way. Seems a little bit redundant...but it works and the warning went away.